# Why am I getting "addresssanitizer deadly signal" while trying to operate on linked lists?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having some problems wrapping my head around struct pointers in this exercise.

The ListNode looks like this:

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
  };
```

I have two ListNodes that I need to add up, the values inside the nodes are between 0 and 9, say if l1 and l2 are [1,2,3] and [4,5,6] I need to get [5,7,9] where 5 is the first node and 9 is the last.

```
struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2){
    struct ListNode* root = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    struct ListNode* node = root;
    int n;
    n = 0;
    while (l1 || l2 || n){
        // if l1 is initialized add it's value to n and move it
        if (l1){
            n += l1->val;
            l1 = l1->next;
        }
        if (l2){
            n += l2->val;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
        node->val = n % 10;
        printf("%d\n",node->val);
        // initialize and move on to the next node
        node = node->next = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        // carry
        n /= 10;
    }
    // when everything is exhausted I will have a useless node so I am freeing it.
    free(node);
    node = NULL;
    return root;
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have the code that uses this function as the site doesn't share it.

Comment: When you do `free(node)`, who's setting the previous node's `next` to NULL?

Comment: FYI: when you receive an ASAN "deadly signal" you should see a little bit more info dumped along with that, like a stack trace and possibly a description of the problem. Use it to help yourself debugging (and maybe attach it to the question, which would be useful).

Comment: @P.P yep, that was it... thanks a lot :)